# What is the phrase in these verses from Bhāgavata Purāṇa referring to?

Tags: scripture, philosophy, bhagavata-purana, interpretation, buddhi

Following is the translation of verses (3.20.49-51) from Bhāgavata Purāṇa by A.C. Bhaktivedanta Swami. https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb

> One day Brahmā, the self-born, the first living creature, felt as if the object of his life had been accomplished. At that time he evolved from his mind the Manus, who promote the welfare activities of the universe. (3.20.49)
> The self-possessed creator gave **them his own human form**. On seeing the Manus, those who had been created earlier — the demigods, the Gāndharvas and so on — applauded Brahmā, the lord of the universe. (3.20.50)
> They prayed: "O creator of the universe, we are glad; what you have produced is well done. Since ritualistic acts have now been established soundly in **this human form**, we shall all share the sacrificial oblations." (3.2.51)

Is the bolded phrase referring to the intellect?

Comment: you need to give the exact verse and who the translator is. You are reading an English translation.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Ji i think its SB 3.20.49; Translation is by i think Srila Prabhupada....

Comment: Yes @Ramachandra

Comment: @Shashaank What does it mean?

Comment: I replied to Ramachandra

Comment: I added citation to answer

Comment: It's actually 3.20.49-51, containing 3 verses (49, 50, 51). I have submitted an edit and have also provided in the link. The translation you have used seems to be of A.C. Bhaktivedanta Swami, so I have added that info in edit.

Answer (score 1):

**ŚB 3.20.50.:**

> *तेभ्य: सोऽसृज**त्स्वीयं पुरं पुरुषमात्मवान्** ।
> तान् दृष्ट्वा ये पुरा सृष्टा: प्रशशंसु: प्रजापतिम् ॥ ५० ॥*
>
> *The self-possessed (atmavān) creator gave them **his own human form.** On seeing the Manus, those who had been created earlier — the demigods, the Gandharvas and so on — applauded Brahmā, the lord of the universe.*

Here, Purusha is translated as Human but Purusha can also mean Divine.

So, it can also be translated as *He gave Manu his own Divine form*.

Plus, Puram can also mean abode.

But, as Manu is a human and we being human are called as Manu Vanshi, so i guess this translation was used.

**Importance of Human form.:**

**Aitreya Upanishad.:**

> *तमभ्यतपत्तस्याभितप्तस्य मुखं निरभिद्यत यथाऽण्डं मुखाद्वाग्वाचोऽग्निर्नासिके निरभिद्येतं नासिकाभ्यां प्राणः प्राणाद्वायुरक्षिणी निरभिद्येतमक्षीभ्यां चक्षुश्चक्षुष आदित्यः कर्णौ निरभिद्येतां कर्णाभ्यां श्रोत्रं श्रोत्रद्दिशस्त्वङ्निरभिद्यत त्वचो लोमानि लोमभ्य ओषधिवनस्पतयो हृदयं निरभिद्यत हृदयान्मनो मनसश्चन्द्रमा नाभिर्निरभिद्यत नाभ्या अपानोऽपानान्मृत्युः शिश्नं निरभिद्यत शिश्नाद्रेतो रेतस आपः ॥४॥*
>
> *I:i:4.:-> He (Self/Atman/Purusha) did penance with the resolution (of creation). From that austerity, an egg like mouth (face) was born. From the mouth (after parting/cracking) emerged speech (vāk); from speech came Fire. The nostrils parted; from the nostrils came out the sense of smell; from the sense of smell came Vayu (Air). The two eyes parted; from the eyes emerged the sense of sight; from the sense of sight came the Sun. The two ears parted; from the ears came the sense of hearing; from the sense of hearing came the Directions. The skin emerged; from the skin came out hair (i.e. the sense of touch associated with hair); from the sense of touch came the Herbs and Trees. The heart took shape; from the heart issued the internal organ (mind/manas); from the internal organ (manas) came the Moon. The navel parted; from the navel came out the organ of ejection; from the organ of ejection issued Death. The seat of the procreative organ parted; from that came the procreative organ; from the procreative organ came out Water.*
>
> *ता एता देवताः सृष्टा अस्मिन्महत्यर्णवे प्रापतन् । तमशनापिपासाभ्यामन्ववार्जत् । ता एनमब्रुवन्नायतनं नः प्रजानीहि यस्मिन्प्रतिष्ठिता अन्नमदामेति ॥१॥*
>
> *I-ii-1: These deities (senses), that had been created, fell into this vast ocean. He (Purusha) subjected them to hunger and thirst. They said to Him, "Provide an abode for us, staying where we can eat food."*
>
> *ताभ्यो गामानयत्ता अब्रुवन्न वै नोऽयमलमिति । ताभ्योऽश्वमानयत्ता अब्रुवन्न वै नोऽयमलमिति ॥२॥*
>
> *I-ii-2: For them He (Purusha) brought a cow. They said, "This one is not certainly adequate for us." For them He brought a horse. They said, "This one is not certainly adequate for us."*
>
> *ताभ्यः पुरुषमानयत्ता अब्रुवन् **सुकृतं बतेति पुरुषो वाव सुकृतम् ।** ता अब्रवीद्यथायतनं प्रविशतेति ॥३॥*
>
> *I-ii-3: For them He brought a man. They said **"This one is well formed; man indeed is a creation of Purusha Brahman Himself".** To them He said, "Enter into your respective abodes".*
>
> *अग्निर्वाग्भूत्वा मुखं प्राविशद्वायुः प्राणो भूत्वा नासिकेप्राविशदादित्यश्चक्षुर्भूत्वाऽक्षिणी प्राविशाद्दिशः श्रोत्रं भूत्वा कर्णौ प्राविशन्नोषधिवनस्पतयो लोमानि भूत्वा त्वचंप्राविशंश्चन्द्रमा मनो भूत्वा हृदयं प्राविशन्मृत्युरपानो भूत्वा नाभिं प्राविशदापोरेतो भूत्वा शिश्नं प्राविशन् ॥४॥*
>
> *I-ii-4: Fire entered into the mouth taking the form of the organ of speech; Air entered into the nostrils assuming the form of the sense of smell; the Sun entered into the eyes as the sense of sight; the Directions entered into the ears by becoming the sense of hearing; the Herbs and Trees entered into the skin in the form of hair (i.e. the sense of touch); the Moon entered into the heart in the shape of the mind; Death entered into the navel in the form of Apana (i.e. the vital energy that presses down); Water entered into the limb of generation in the form of semen (i.e. the organ of procreation).*
>
> *तमशनायापिपासे अब्रूतामावाभ्यामभिप्रजानीहीति ते अब्रवीदेतास्वेव वां देवतास्वाभजाम्येतासु भागिन्न्यौ करोमीति । तस्माद्यस्यै कस्यै च देवतायै हविर्गृह्यते भागिन्यावेवास्यामशनायापिपासे भवतः ॥५॥*
>
> *I-ii-5: To Him Hunger and Thirst said, "Provide for us (some abode)." To them He said, "I provide your livelihood among these very gods; I make you share in their portions." Therefore when oblation is taken up for any deity whichsoever, Hunger and Thirst become verily sharers with that deity.*

**Conclusion.:** Human form is the best abode for the gods.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142019/discussion-on-answer-by-savdy-what-is-the-phrase-in-these-verses-from-bhgavata).